# how to understand such a macro definition in the book programming Clojure 2nd 's page 173?

Tags: clojure, macros

I'am reading [Programming Clojure 2nd](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781934356869.do)'s `Making Macros Simpler` in `p173`, there is a macro definition as follows:

```
(defmacro chain 
    ([x form] (list '. x form))
    ([x form & more] (concat (list 'chain (list '. x form)) more)))
```

But according to the definition about `defmacro` in `p167`:

```
(defmacro name doc-string? attr-map? [params*] body)
```

From the definition `chain`, I can guess and verify that `[x form]` is parameters of `chain`, but obviously,

`([x form] (list '. x form))
        ([x form & more] (concat (list 'chain (list '. x form)) more))`

is the `body` of `chain`, why the parameters of the `body` is changed into the one of `chain`?  Or can I understand this is a clojure'
's `overloading` like `java`?  what something I missed?

UPDATED: I googled the result about clojure's [overloading](https://clojure.org/about/functional_programming), but I did not find the description about `overloading` in the book

Comment: @Thumbnail, thank you! Your explanation is the same as the result I googled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two forms within `(defmacro chain ... )` represent different [arities](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#__em_fn_em_name_params_exprs) of the macro - taking different numbers of arguments.

- The first body form `([x form] ...)`, takes two
  arguments.
- The second body form, `([x form & more] ...)` accepts any number of
  arguments greater than two (were it not for the first form, it would
  accept two too).

You'll find the explanation of functions with multiple arities (`defmacro` expands to a `fn` form) on page 33 of the book.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure functions and macros can have multiple arities.

The current docs for `defmacro` says that it takes the following arguments.

```
([name doc-string? attr-map? [params*] body]
 [name doc-string? attr-map? ([params*] body) + attr-map?])
```

Where the `([params*] body)` part can be repeated multiple times, as long as there's no ambiguity between them.

The `([params*] body)` part is the same as in `fn` and `defn`.

```
(defmacro foo
  ([x y] ,,,)
  ([x y & xs] ,,,)
```

If this is called with two arguments, it'll use the first arity.
If it is called with three or more it'll use the second one.

```
(defmacro bar
  [x y & xs]
  ,,,)
```

This one can be called with two arguments, in which case xs will be empty.